# Quest qad-newuser from csv not setting lastname

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, quest

Have this script

```
Import-Csv "c:\newuserscopy.csv" | ForEach-Object {
 $userPrinc = $_."SamAccountName" + "@mydomainco.uk"
 New-QADUser -Name $_."Name" `
 -ParentContainer $_."Path" `
 -SamAccountName $_."SamAccountName" `
 -UserPassword "Today01" `
 -FirstName $_."FirstName" `
 -LastName $_."LastName" `
 -City $_."City" `
 -LogonScript "login.bat" `
 -Title $_."Title" `
 -PostalCode $_."PostalCode" `
 -HomeDirectory $_."HomeDirectory" `
 -HomeDrive $_."M:" `
 -StateOrProvince $_."StateOrProvince" `
 -UserPrincipalName $userPrinc `
 -DisplayName $_."Name" ;`
}
```

Only thing is the PostalCode and LastName do not get added to the account for some reason. Can any one spot what I am doing wrong? Everything else fits just not that...

CSV:

Name,DisplayName,FirstName,LastName ,SamAccountName,Path,City,LogonScript,HomeDirectory,HomeDrive,Title,StateOrProvince,PostalCode ,LogonName,UserPrincipalName
NTEST,Niel DTEST,NDTEST,test,ND999,"OU=City,OU=Localtion,DC=DOMAIN,DC=co,DC=uk",London,login.bat,\fileshare\nd999,M:,TEST IT Support,local,n1ao1,ND999,ND999@Domain.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: The semi-colon and the back tick just before the closing brace of your foreach loop seems strange to me. Are you sure you copy/pasted the code from your script directly? Also, without seeing your csv file, it's hard to give you any meaningful answer.

Comment: Added CSV thanks for your help. Just cant seem to get it to set -LastName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSV data is an exact copy/paste then the label of the "Last Name" and "Postal Code" fields have a trailing space so the field name is actually **"Last Name "** and **"Postal Code "** not **"Last Name"** and **"Postal Code"** like it is referred to in the script.  Fix those and the data should fill in properly.

Other things that might be wrong are

**-HomeDrive $_."M:" `**

probably should be **-HomeDrive "M:" `**

and **-UserPrincipalName $userPrinc `**

probably should be **-UserPrincipalName $_."UserPrincipalName" `**